# Apache　ドキュメントルートの変更

Tags: apache

Apacheのドキュメントルートを変更したく、configファイルをいじったんですが、うまく変更できていないみたいなんです・・・

> DocumentRoot "/home/ryo/www/public"

と変更したのですが、他に変更する場所があるのですか？
教えてください。

Answer (score 0, accepted):

デフォルトの /etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf を編集しているという前提で、

```
<Directory "/var/www/html">
```

の部分を

```
<Directory "/home/ryo/www/public">
```

に変更します。

ただ、本来は /etc/httpd/conf.d/ 配下に conf ファイルを作成して管理した方がよいでしょう。

Comment: Directory　という項目が３箇所ほどあるんですが、全部変更する必要がありますか？

Comment: /home/ryo/www/public　にApacheがアクセスできるように設定する必要がありますかね？
それともファイアウォールですかね？
ファイアウォールはufwで管理していて、80番ポートは開いています...

Comment: /etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf を変更しているということで相違ありませんか？ /etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf の Directory ディレクティブは4箇所ですが、変更は `<Directory "/var/www/html">` のみで問題ありません。ufw は利用したことがありませんが、CentOS 7 ではデフォルトで FirewallD が有効のはずなので、競合してないか確認した方が良いかもしれません。

Comment: 少し思い違いをしていましたが、403 Forbidden エラーで表示されない状態でしょうか。CentOS 7 ではデフォルトで SELinux が有効になっているので、分からない内は `setenforce 0` などで一時的に無効にした方が早いかもしれません。またディレクトリやファイルのパーミッションの設定なども確認した方がいいでしょう。正直なところ CentOS で /home ディレクトリ配下にドキュメントルートを配置すると手間が増えます。

Comment: /home に配置しないとCyberduckからファイルのアップロードができないんです・・・・・

Comment: <Directory "/var/www/html">　を変更しても変更されなくて、DocumentRoot "/home/ryo/www/public"　とDocumentRootを変更したら、４０３エラーで”You don't have permission to access / on this server.”接続する権限がないと言われます。
chmodでパーミッションをApacheグループもアクセスできるようにするにはどうすればいいですか？